# WPF control always rendered as topmost in web page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using ElementHost (.NET Framework 4) to host a WPF control in a web page:

```
private MyWpfRichTextBoxControl control;
private ElementHost elementHost;
...

{
    control = new MyWpfRichTextBoxControl();
    elementHost = new ElementHost { Child = control };
    Controls.Add(elementHost);
    ...
}
```

The WPF control is functional inside the web page.  However the problem is that because it is rendered as the topmost element on the page other web components are always rendered underneath the control.  For example if there were a drop down box just above the control and the user pulled it down then the menu would go under the control rather than go over it.

Are there any options or tricks I can use to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible due to the [airspace issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa970688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you mix other UI technologies with WPF they cannot overlap.